# Python Tkinter IntVar Not Updating

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have two functions that are part of a Python 3.4.1 Tkinter GUI.

```
def jumpto():
    global jump
    jump = Tk()
    jump.wm_title("Jump")
    jump.focus_force()
    label = Label(jump, text = "Enter digit to jump:").pack()
    global jumptext
    jumptext = IntVar()
    jumpentry = Entry(jump, textvariable = jumptext)
    jumpentry.pack()
    jump.bind("<Return>", close)

def close(self):
    global jumptext
    global jump
    print(jumptext.get())
    while digit < jumptext.get(): #digit is an integer that increases in the unrelated area below
        #Do something completely unrelated
    jump.destroy()

jButton = Button(master, text = "JUMP", command = jumpto).pack() #master is the main Tk window
```

However, when I run the code, `jumptext.get()` within `close` remains 0, despite something being typed in to the entry box created with `jumpentry`. Any way to make it so that the information entered actually updates to `jumptext.get()`?

Also, if anyone could explain to me why `self` must be entered within `close`, that would be a bonus.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that you're making two instances of `Tk()`, which leads to strange behavior. The `jump` window should be a [`Toplevel`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111195659/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) window, which is the window to use if you want another window next to your `Tk()` window.

`close` needs to accept an argument because it is called by a `bind` which always passes an [event](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111215134/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) object which contains all kinds of information about the event that triggered the `close` function (things like mouse position and the key that was used to trigger the event). So calling it `event` instead of `self` would actually be more correct. `self` is a variable used in classes which contains class attributes.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would +1, but I apparently need more rep for that. Still, amazing explanation.